# conditional functional component rendering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have following code:

[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-kirch-ue2wz)

What I would like is to when "load" is true then return:

```
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
       </div>
```

else return empty object

Comment: In particular, always include all information (code, ...) directly in your question description. Using additional off-side resources is great as long as the question can be understood and answered without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we cant directly render empty object in JSX. we can do like that or use empty string

```
export default function App() {
  let load = true;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {load === true ? <h1>Loading... </h1> : <h1>no data</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```